# I can't override Tomcat's default Welcome File List

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to override Tomcat's (version 7) default Welcome File List, as its conf/web.xml suggests by declaring a 'welcome-file-list' tag in the following form

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>estore.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>estore.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>estore.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

in my application's web.xml , but I am getting an error like this :

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.estore_jsp

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the files are available in WEB-INF/estore.html and so on?

Comment: I've just renamed the index.jsp file that is placed in the web directory of the project to estore.jsp

Comment: If you look in the webapps/yourapp folder on Tomcat, do you actually see the estore.jsp??

Comment: No I can't find it there.

Comment: Maybe redirection is the only way that works..take a look at this link : http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F

Comment: If the file is not there, it means you didn't copy it there and it HAS to be there if you want to show something. Redirect will fail too as there's no jsp to serve. How are you deploying your project in tomcat?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 12.Deployment has worked fine for many projects until now that I want to change the name of the default starting jsp file from index.jsp to estore.jsp .Can you explain why the instructions given inside Tomcat's own web.xml are not working?

Comment: The problem seemed to be at another place of the project and specifically in a wrong function name declaration in my custom tld file.Now the application runs without problem and the overriding worked!

Comment: As you had errors, the deployment failed and your jsp was not being uploaded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

1. Add the above snippet in your web.xml
2. Then in index.html, I would use a `<link />` tag to forward to my desired landing page, i.e. estore.html in your case.

This should do it.

Comment: The override should work for a given context, without hacks that must be mantained and documented later.

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat default deployment descriptor file is located in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml.Over there you would find the default description for tag as:

```
<welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

indent <!--   --> the above code and save the /conf/web.xml file. Now place your code

```
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>estore.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>estore.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>estore.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

in WEB-INF/web.xml of the project and restart the tomcat server you would get the result.